# Unserialize field value created in Advanced Custom Fields to be exported in xml

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to export some content with custom fields in Wordpress. The custom fields were created via **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin and the exporting tool I am using is **WP All Export Pro**. The fields that are created via Advanced Custom Fields are serialized and therefore even the output in xml is serialized, but I need to unserialize it ...

This tutorial: https://www.boilingpotmedia.com/unserialize-data-wordpress/ should solve exactly what I am looking for to have solved. It looked really promising as it deals with exact same issue as I have, but unfortunately, it did not work, I got following error:

*PHP Error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 6 of the Functions Editor*

The code I use (as in the link):

```
<?php
function data_deserialize($value){
$output = '';
$data = maybe_unserialize($value);
$data = $data[0];
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
$output .= $key.': '.$value.'
';
}
return $output;
}
?>
```

Since I am not developer, this is difficult for me to fix it ... Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see what the `$value` actually contains.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware. Thanks for your reply ... this is an example of the field: <market_info_targeting>a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Distributors";i:1;s:16:"Service Partners";}</market_info_targeting>

Comment: As a WordPress developer, that function would only seem to work for a very specific set of serialized data, not every, or even most cases. One of the main reasons that data is serialized in the first place is because it doesn’t conform to a structure that can be universally described in a database. If, however, that sample represents all of your data, you could try this version of that function: https://3v4l.org/2gGGU